# The type or namespace name 'MyApplication' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an old ASP.NET C# web application which I am trying to upgrade and update in Visual Studio 2015.

After opening the project and trying to build it, I get the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'MyApplication' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

`Global.asax`:

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" 
    Inherits="MyApplication.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>`
```

`Global.asax.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MyApplication
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Data", action = "WarehouseDataReview", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

What I tried:

- Adding the `System.mvc` reference
- Saving and reopening Visual Studio 2015

Comment: It would probably be simpler just to create a new empty project (Startup, Application...) and add all the existing code there, instead of trying to update from some old MVC version

Comment: Hi Eugene, this solved my problem. Created a new solution with we web project. Added the old C#  project and removed the new one. An it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

this solved my problem. Created a new solution with we web project. Added the old C#  project and removed the new one. An it worked fine.